# Find the number of prime numbers p such that $2p^{4} − 7p^{2} + 1$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Have been trying to find the number of prime numbers $p$ such that  $2p^{4} − 7p^{2} + 1$ is a perfect square.

$$
2p^{4} − 7p^{2} + 1 = n^{2} \\
2p^{4} - 7p^{2} = n^{2} - 1
$$

How do I move ahead?

Comment: $2p^4 − 7p^2 + 1 = n^2 \implies (4 p^2 - 7)^2 - 2 (2 n)^2 = 41$

Comment: @DmitryEzhov but the answer has to be a perfect square which 41 is not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $p\ne 3$.  Then $p\in\{1,2\}\bmod 3$ meaning $p^4\equiv p^2\equiv 1$.  Plug that in and we get

$2p^4-7p^2+1\equiv-4\equiv 2\bmod 3$,

which could pose a little problem.

The prime $3$ is outside this proof and it works by trial.

Comment: Proving by contradiction you mean?

Comment: That's the little problem.  Yes I have a strange sense of humor.